# IE10 transition not working properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, transform

I am creating a slider which will move boxes to the left/right. It works perfectly on Chrome and FireFox. But on IE10, after moving to the left, it is like:

[image]

It looks like the moving is jumpy. The right border has multiple slight copies (not sure how to describe.).

My SASS is like:

```
@include transition-timing-function(cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1))
@include transition-duration(500ms)
```

After clicking the left/right button, the JavaScript making the move is:

```
$scroller.css({
    'transform': "translate(-" + scrollLeftPosition + "px, 0px) translateZ(0px)"
 });
```

Consulting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), it seems that the property `transform` is supported by IE10. How to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is IE page rendering. Temply solved the problem by changing the width slightly after the animation (so that the browser will re-render the view):

```
$slider.width(viewWidth + 1);
$timeout(function () {
    $slider.width(viewWidth);
}, 600);
```